# Установка или компиляция Phalcon

Tags: php, ubuntu, phalcon

По документации https://phalconphp.com/en/download пробую 5-й день поставить Phalcon на Ubuntu 16.04.1, php7.0

Выполняю:

```
# Ubuntu 16.04+ or Debian 9+
sudo apt-get install php7.0-phalcon
```

А терминал мне:

```
E: Не удалось найти пакет php7.0-phalcon
E: Не удалось найти пакет с помощью glob «php7.0-phalcon»
E: Не удалось найти пакет с помощью regex «php7.0-phalcon»
```

Попробовал это:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:phalcon/legacy
```

И опять пробую шаг выше — те же ошибки, ну что же, есть еще один вариант — скомпилировать! Делаю:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-dev php7.0-mysql gcc libpcre3-dev
```

Есть, хорошо! Иду в /opt, клонирую, иду в папку cphalcon/build и запускаю:

```
sudo ./install
```

Доходит до:

`libtool: compile:  gcc -I. -I/opt/cphalcon/build/php7/64bits -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/opt/cphalcon/build/php7/64bits/include -I/opt/cphalcon/build/php7/64bits/main -I/opt/cphalcon/build/php7/64bits -I/usr/include/php/20151012 -I/usr/include/php/20151012/main -I/usr/include/php/20151012/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20151012/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20151012/ext -I/usr/include/php/20151012/ext/date/lib -DPHALCON_RELEASE -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -march=native -mtune=native -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer -fvisibility=hidden -c /opt/cphalcon/build/php7/64bits/phalcon.zep.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/phalcon.o`

Начинает использоваться диск на 100%, жду это все дело около 30 минут, надоедает и жму `Ctrl+C`, получаю:
`^CMakefile:194: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «phalcon.lo»
make: *** [phalcon.lo] Ошибка 1`

Делаю на VirtualBox.

Comment: Эту команду выполняли? `curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/phalcon/stable/script.deb.sh | sudo bash`

Comment: Не, думал это к старым версиям Ubuntu относится...

Comment: А самую первую команду, `curl -s "https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/phalcon/stable/script.deb.sh" | sudo bash`, выполнил?

Comment: И `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:phalcon/legacy` - это установка версии 1.х, вряд ли она нужна, сейчас уже 3.х имеется.

Comment: Нет, к старым версиям Убунты, как и к старым версиям Дебиана, относится только лишь `sudo apt-get install php5-phalcon` - так как там банально php7 не будет. Но скрипт, который подготовит всю хурму, находится как раз в той первой строке. Если получится как я предлагаю установить, дай знать, я вынесу комментарии отсюда в отдельный ответ.

Comment: А у вас на виртуалке памяти достаточно? Компиляция типично должна упираться в CPU. А вот если памяти не хватает и начинает процесс дико свопится - то как раз и будет 100% диск и стремящийся к бесконечности процесс.

Answer (score 0):

сделай лучше git clone  phalcon и пробуй с этими исходниками собрать

> git clone --depth=1 git://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon.git
>   cd cphalcon/build
>   sudo ./install